# Shell Script for adding base_url to the php files

Tags: shell, scripting, ubuntu, rename

I have a website setup in which there are a lot of files mostly php. But in this i am calling the files as say /model/login/......

I want to rename all such occurences as $base_url/model/login/....

How can I approach the problem or where can I get the tutorials for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sed](http://www.google.com/search?q=sed+tutorial) can do this trivially, provided you don't use the path for anything else in the code.

```
sed -i 's!/model/login/!$base_url&!g' foo.php
```

Comment: It would probably be more maintainable just to modify the include path to include $base_url...

Comment: can you elaborate a little more on the above solution

Comment: It depends on how `$base_url` is set. Frobbing include paths at runtime is generally a bad smell.

Comment: @ingacio the distinguising factor between /admin in between and in the start can be that the url must start from "/admin and hence can we incorporate " in the above script

Comment: Like on doing grep -R \"\/web *         i get all such occurences.. now i have to change dese to \"\$base_url\/web how can i do that